# Which is better for a laptop? DDR3 SDRAM or SODIMM?

Tags: sodimm

I am deciding between 2 HP laptops.  One has DDR3 SDRAM and the other has SO DIMM.  Which is better?

Comment: SO-DIMM is the packaging. DDR3 is the type of memory. It's not either/or. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SO-DIMM

Comment: These both DDR3 modules?  The physical size of the module wouldn't matter.  What makes a difference is the voltage, memory size, and frequnecy of the modules.

Answer (score 2):

SO-DIMM Ram is just the label applied to the shorter laptop memory. SO-DIMM DDR3 RAM would be considered SDRAM.